# How to scan strings from a text file with delimiter and then display it?

Tags: c, loops, text-files

So i tried to make a program that will scan strings from a text file and then display it using loop. But, somehow my program cannot work and it is display weird symbols.. i am new to text file and i would appreciate a lot if someone can explain to me what is wrong with my code.

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("alumni.txt", "r");
    if (fPtr == NULL) {
        printf("There is a error opening the file.");
        exit(-1);
    }
   
    char name[20], design[50], category[20], location[20];
    
    while (fscanf(fPtr, "%s:%[^\n]:%[^\n]:%[^\n]", &name, &design, &category, &location) != EOF) {
        printf("Name : %s\n", name);
        printf("Designation : %s\n", design);
        printf("Category : %s\n", category);
        printf("Location : %s\n", location);
    }
}
```

and this is my text file,

```
Shanie:Programmer:Full Time:Kuala Lumpur
Andy:Sales Agent:Part Time:Johor Bahru
Elaine:Database Administrator Full Time Melaka
Stephanie:MIS manager:Full Time:Penang
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* problems: The first is that `%s` will read *space* delimited "words", it won't stop at the `:`. The second problem is that the format `%[^\n]` reads *all* until newline.

So you need a scanset format for the first `name` as well as tell it to read until the next `:`, which is done with the format `%[^:]`.

So please change to:

```
while (fscanf(fPtr, " %19[^:]:%49[^:]:%19[^:]:%19[^\n]", name, design, category, location) == 4) {
    ...
}
```

Please note a couple of other changes I made to your call and loop condition: First of all, I have added length specifiers to the formats, so `fscanf` will not write out of bounds of your arrays.

Secondly both the `%s` and `%[]` formats expects a `char *` argument, while you provided a pointer to arrays (`&name` will be of type `char (*)[20]` not `char *`). Arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first element, so e.g. `name` will decay to `&name[0]` which will be of the correct type `char *`.

Thirdly I changed the comparison to compare against `4`, which is what `fscanf` will [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) if it successfully parsed the input.

Lastly I added a space before the first format, to skip any leading space (like the newline from the previous line).

---

To be sure to be able to continue even in the case of malformed input, I recommend you read full lines instead (using e.g. `fgets`), and then possibly use `sscanf` to parse each line.

Comment: Bro i followed your advice and it worked, but somehow after the first set of loop it will automatically enter to a new line after Name, like Name : then new line Andy, i can't seems to find out why tho

Comment: @YongYungFook Yeah I forgot to skip the newline. Updated answer.